# Como fazer a função mail() do PHP enviar via Amazon SES?

Tags: amazon-aws, phpmailer, email, postfix, ses

Como fazer com que a função *mail()* do **PHP** utilize minhas credenciais na **Amazon SES** para enviar emails transacionais sem precisar utilizar a lib **PHPMailer** ou ter que instalar e configurar o **postfix**/**sendmail** para essa finalidade?

Isso é uma boa pratica? Se não, porque?

Comment: Da uma olhadinha no próprio site da ses amazon que lá na documentação tem exatamente este exemplo de como usar com php, já vi isso lá.

Comment: Na pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65870/simples-formul%C3%A1rio-de-contato-enviando-email-via-amazon-ses-com-php/65996#65996 é tratado deste tema

Comment: O SES da amazon vc usa a propria lib deles, nao é nem via `mail`, nem `PHPMailer`. E não...mesmo que isso fosse possivel isso nao é uma boa prática. A função `mail` do PHP é a função mais inútil que tem na linguagem.

Comment: eu geralmente uso o SQS para adicionar emails numa fila e rodo um cron enviando tudo que ta na fila de 1 em 1 minuto através do SES.