# Simples formulário de contato enviando email via Amazon SES com PHP

Tags: php, amazon-aws, postfix, ses, mailer

Para um simples formulário de contato pretendo utilizar o Amazon SES com PHP. Basicamente o PHP vai enviar um email para mim mesmo com o email do usuário que me contactou para dar uma resposta.

Pesquisando, me deparei com as seguintes alternativas:

1. Utilizar a classe PHP Mailer com as credenciais do Amazon SES.
2. Configurar o Postfix como relay do Amazon SES para utilizar a função mail() do PHP.
3. Utilizar o PHP Mailer juntamente com o Postfix como relay do Amazon SES.

**Dúvidas:**

1. Qual a finalidade de utilizar o Postfix como relay do SES se posso apenas utilizar o PHP Mailer informando o servidor e credenciais?
2. Porque algumas pessoas configuram o Postfix como relay do SES e mesmo assim utilizam o PHP Mailer, mesmo o PHP Mailer sendo capaz de utilizar o SES diretamente?
3. Qual a melhor pratica, utilizando o Amazon SES, para enviar emails de contato e emails transacionais simples com PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As três alternativas funcionam,
porém você deve considerar a necessidade de resistência da aplicação e a quantidade de envio.

Na alternativa 1, seu sistema está conectado diretamente no SMTP da Aws e está bloqueado enquanto opera a lista de envio, enquanto nas opções **2** e **3** o sistema delega ao Serviço de email local a tarefa de comunicar a fila de mensagens para a AWS, o que pode acontecer de maneira muito rápida e liberar o sistema para dar sequência a outras atividades.

Para um sistema simples como o formulário de contato, use a opção **1** mas para mensagens transacionais de uma aplicação eu recomendo uma estrutura mais robusta como a opção **3** que você mencionou.

Comment: Certo. No caso existe uma 4ª alternativa, que seria utilizar a API em PHP do Amazon SES. Essa substituiria a necessidade de usar um servidor SMTP local para emails transacionais sem bloquear a fila? Qual a melhor maneira de enviar emails transacionais sem usar um servidor SMTP local como o SendMail e Postfix?

Comment: Na minha opinião, a melhor maneira é implementar o uso do pacote php swiftmailer (http://swiftmailer.org/) e sua estratégia avançada para fila. Mas como você disse que era algo simples, o swiftmailer seria um canhão para matar um mosca :)